# Assign fixed layout to dynamic textview

Tags: android, layout, textview

Hello
I have a loop that creates n-1 textviews, and for each of these textviews I would like a fixed layout defined in an XML file.

The code is as follows:

```
for(PInfo P : P_array)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(P.getName());
        tv.setWidth(P.getLength());
        tv.setHeight(70);
        tv.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
        masterView.addView(tv);
    }
```

I would like something like tv.setLayout(R.id.textviewlayout); ... How is that done, im sure its easy (it should be) but I cant find any info on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called inflating. Try this:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TextView tv = li.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
```

Second parameter is optional parent for inflated view:
[help article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Comment: Thank you very much. (Only issue was that you needed to cast.
TextView tv = (TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but have a look in the SDK reference for `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`.

This will enable you to build a list of custom views from an XML file.